# My user is getting an unbound local error in a selenium based script i wrote

Tags: python, selenium

This program scrapes data from a web app. it worked on my computer, but the user is getting an unbound local error in the box_input method. [Error the user sent me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dV0OH.png) 
Now, I'm not sure if this is a scope error? Or does this mean that the assignment if binput is not finding the html element? Any help would be appreciated, here is the code: https://github.com/nhallen272/InundationAnalysisScraper

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow.  Please see [ask] and [edit] your question with a [mre] or the relevant parts of your code, as well as the error message in text directly within the body of the question itself.

Answer (score 0):

It's because `binput` wasn't assigned before the `try` block.  You cannot assign an object within the `try` block and expect `finally` to handle the same object.  What if the `try` failed? `binput` would not exist, and therefore `binput.click()` would become an error within the `finally` portion itself.  Also, you should be adding an `except` to handle the exceptions that occur within `try`.

You'll need to restructure your logic a little bit, maybe like this:

```
try:
    binput = self.find_element_by_css_selector(css_selector)
    binput.click()
        if isYear:
            for i in range(4):
                binput.send_keys(Keys.BACK_SPACE)
        else:
            binput.send_keys(input_value)
except:  # tag the appropriate errors, such as ElementNotFoundError
    # Handle your case if Element is not found
finally:
    # Handle codes that do not rely on binput to exist.
```